# Does a RFID antenna need to be FCC certified?

Tags: rfid, antenna, fcc

Being a RFID UHF antenna a "passive" element does it need to be FCC certified? Or, we just need to have the RFID UHF reader certified?

Answer (score 5):

A antenna by itself does not radiate, so can't be certified.  The entire unit of a intential radiator, including the antenna, absolutely needs to have FCC certification if you want to legally sell it in the United States.

If this antenna is connected to a receiver-only device that never intentionally radiates, then certification is not required.  However, it still must meet the radiation limits for a unintentional radiator, but it is up to you to make sure of that.  You don't have to get it tested, but if there is a complaint and the FCC finds it violating the limits, you're in deep doodoo.

Comment: Not that I doubt you, but do you have a cite for the relevant FCC regulations here?

Comment: @Obscure: No, this is just what I've gathered from projects that went thru this.  I am not a lawyer and this isn't legal advice.

Comment: I was just poking around on [fcc.gov](http://www.fcc.gov/) and couldn't find anything relevant either. They seem to be very broadband focused.

Comment: Also, I am not sure what you mean by fcc.gov being very broadband focused. They have every rule here http://wireless.fcc.gov/index.htm?job=rules_and_regulations

Comment: If you go to fcc.gov and click on the "Tools & Data" tab, most of that stuff seems to be focused on broadband deployment. I get that the exact rules and regulations are available there. What I would have liked to see is something like a hardware designers RF licensing FAQ which would have a decision tree that points you at the regulations relevant to your project.

Comment: @Obscure: Maybe poke around in part 15.

Comment: I'll pass, but I was going to suggest that you post a link to the relevant documentation in your question. Since the link points to a long list of PDFs, I'll just go back to coding and continue to be happy that I was never an EE for more than a semester :)

Comment: Thank you for your contributions.
OK, it's clear that an antenna by itself does not radiate, so can't be certified. But at the same time we should test to guarantee that it does not exceed radiation limits with any unintentional radiator.